# Create field containing 2 different fields' data based on condition in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

**The Setup:**

My database has 3 tables that I need to work with. Let's call the first two `PartList` and `PartHist`. `PartList` contains all the part numbers that go on a machine (We'll call this field `ExpectedPart`). `PartHist` contains all the components that have been verified to be on a machine (`VerifiedPart`). Both tables contain a `MachineID` field that references a specific, physical machine.

So far, my query looks as follows:

```
SELECT
    ExpectedPart,
    VerifiedPart
FROM
    PartList List
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PartHist Hist
ON
    List.MachineID = Hist.MachineID
    AND List.ExpectedPart = Hist.VerifiedPart
Where
    List.MachineID = 'SomeID'
```

**The Problem:**

So far, this query works very nicely to tell which components have not yet been verified, as the value of `VerifiedPart` is `NULL` until that part has been verified. Except for in one specific part, where the part number is in the `PartList`, but its verification is stored in another table (not my fault). So, even after it has been verified, the query returns `NULL` for this part.

This third table, we'll call it `SpecialCase`, has `MachineID` and `VerifiedPartSP` fields. There is also a field in the `PartHist` table that contains 'Y' if the part is an instance of this special case part, and 'N' if it is not. This field will be called `SpYesNo`.

**The Question:**
Can I create a single field in the query that contains all of the verified parts? I thought somehow there might be a way to use a condition so that...

```
IF (PartHist.SpYesNo = 'Y') THEN use SpecialCase.VerifiedPartSP as VerifiedPart
```

I'm using an IBM DB2 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just union your two "Verified" parts tables together, then join:

```
SELECT
    ExpectedPart,
    VerifiedPart
FROM
    PartList List
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ( 
            SELECT machineid, verifiedpart FROM PartHist 
            UNION
            SELECT machineid, verifiedpartsp FROM SpecialCase
        )Hist
ON
    List.MachineID = Hist.MachineID
    AND List.ExpectedPart = Hist.VerifiedPart
Where
    List.MachineID = 'SomeID'
```

You could also `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to both of those tables and use a `CASE` statement to check either field, but I think this approach better fits your requirements, and will execute faster.

---

Here is a version with a JOIN and a CASE statement to figure out what's what:

```
SELECT
    ExpectedPart,
    CASE WHEN PartHist.SPYesNo = 'Y' THEN SpecialCase.VerifiedPartSP ELSE partHistVerifiedPart END as VerifiedPart
FROM
    PartList List
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PartHist ON 
        List.MachineID = PartHist.MachineID AND 
        List.ExpectedPart =         PartHist.VerifiedPart
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecialCase ON 
        List.MachineID = SpecialCase.MachineID AND 
        List.ExpectedPart = SpecialCase.VerifiedPart 

Where
    List.MachineID = 'SomeID'
```

Comment: Have tried this, but it seems that our database does not support UNION (or Showcase, which our queries go through won't allow it)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DECODE(VerifiedPart, NULL, ExpectedPart, 
              VerifiedPart) as ValidPart
FROM
    PartList List
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PartHist Hist
ON
    List.MachineID = Hist.MachineID
    AND List.ExpectedPart = Hist.VerifiedPart
Where
    List.MachineID = 'SomeID'
```

Comment: Please comment why the solution is incorrect.  I would like to learn more.  Thank you.

Comment: Did not down-vote, but have a couple questions for you. You have "ValidPart" at the end of the SELECT statement, which I'm assuming you meant as something else, but not exactly sure what. Also, based on reading the description of DECODE, this would look at the VerifiedPart column and, if NULL, would replace the value with ExpectedPart. Otherwise, the value would remain as the original VerifiedPart value. Since this does not access the VerifiedPart value from SpecialCase, I don't see how it solves the problem

Comment: I just used ValidPart as an alias.  You need to have a name, otherwise it will come out as the entire decode statement on output.  I'm unclear as to what specialcase's value is.  Is it just something you want in the output?

Comment: Basically, I'd like to add every record that matches the MachineID from the SpecialCase table, but I'd like all of the values from VerifiedPartSp (in SpecialCase), to be put into the VerifiedPart field of my query. The data is the same (a part number), so I would like it to appear in the same field when the query is run